# AsyncApexJob table has additional record initially? platform bug?

Tags: apex, platform-bug, asyncapexjob

I noticed when creating a new dev org, and running my first batch job. I then query the AsyncApexJob table and there are 2 records instead of the expected 1.

There seems to be a default record in the table when the org is created. Anyone know the reason for this? Is this by design?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [What are the differences between the different possible jobs processed in the 'AsyncApexJob' object?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000228389) for more information on jobs, but specifically they cover ApexToken:

> An 'ApexToken' job is used for Flex Queue enabled organizations. From
>   Winter '16 onwards, the flex queue is enabled by default for all
>   organizations. If an Apex code block invokes
>   Database.executeBatch(),instead of accepting the job directly into
>   Salesforce's queueing system, an 'ApexToken' Job is submitted to the
>   queue. For any batch job that a user submits, a token job is created
>   internally. However, if the maximum number of queued batch jobs in the
>   batch job queue has been reached, the new batch job is placed in a
>   'Holding' state in the flex queue.
>
> 'ApexToken' is our internal mechanism for managing system resources.
>   When a token job gets picked up by the system for execution, it's an
>   indication that the system can take in more jobs from the flex queue.
>
> Note: Every organization has only limited number of 'ApexToken' jobs.
>   This token mechanism allows organizations to submit more batch jobs
>   (maximum is a 100), however only some of them could be running in
>   parallel on the Salesforce platform.

Basically, the system generates these jobs periodically so that the runtime knows that more jobs can be accepted. This is expected, normal behavior.